# Calculating all components of Projectile motion

Tags: physics, projectile-motion

I have a Physics project which requires me to find football passes and calculate based on the data given. I need to find the Initial Velocity, Angle of Release, and max height with only the time and range. I am extremely confused on how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that time period $$T=\frac{2u(\sin\theta)}{g}$$
and range $$R=\frac{u^2\sin2\theta}{g}$$
$$=\frac{2u^2\sin\theta \cos\theta}{g}$$
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{T^2}{R}=\frac{2\tan\theta}{g}$$
Put $g=9.8 ms^{-2}$ and get $\theta$, put that in any of the equations and get u, now use formula for whatever variables you want.

Hope it is helpful:)